# BDD - Issue running with No UI

Tags: selenium-webdriver, rspec, cucumber, poltergeist

I'm new to using cucumber and ruby for doing BDD unit tests and would like to get some help regarding an error that is occurring when try to run the test without the UI.

If I have got any terms or phase incorrect, please let me know.

Scenario : On the page there is a drop down list, which pulls back data once you start typing. In the test, I enter a value and it searches for the data and once it returns I click on the selected value. This is done with the below code,

`selectClient.fill_in 'client', with: client_name
page.has_no_css?('.Select-loading-zone')
selectClient.find('[name=client]').send_keys(:enter)`

selectClient is a var that is used to find the section where the dropdownlist is located so that I don't search the whole page for to find the control.

This works correctly when it is running for the UI but when it is running without the UI I get the following errors, as the selected item is being clicked or selected.

> Capybara::Poltergeist::MouseEventFailed: Firing a click at co-ordinates [122, 261.5] failed. Poltergeist detected another element with CSS selector 'html.no-js body.ng-scope.rebranding div.wrapper.ng-scope div.inner.ng-scope div.container-fluid div.ng-scope div#module-container.ng-scope div.myob section.ledger-upgrade div.row div.col-xs-24 div div div.form-group div.Select.create-business.Select--single.is-searchable div.Select-control span#react-select-2--value.Select-multi-value-wrapper div.Select-placeholder' at this position. It may be overlapping the element you are trying to interact with. If you don't care about overlapping elements, try using node.trigger('click').

I have tried the suggested change by using the following

`selectClient.find('[name=client]').trigger('click')`

This does not seems to work for both the UI and no UI. 
With the UI, I get the following error message

> Capybara::NotSupportedByDriverError: Capybara::Driver::Node#trigger

With no UI, the click does not get fired or selected.

I have tried the following options but still no luck as the selected is not click or selected with no UI.

`selectClient.find('[name=client]', :visible=> false).trigger('click')`
`selectClient.find('[name=client]', :visible=> false).trigger(':enter')`
`selectClient.find('[name=client]', :visible=> false).trigger(':return')`
`selectClient.find('[name=client]', :visible=> false).send_keys : enter`
`selectClient.find('[name=client]', :visible=> false).native.send_keys : return`

I have also tried using Javascript with the below code snippet but does not seem to click or select the when there is no UI.

`page.execute_script('var keyEvent = document.createEventObject ? document.createEventObject() : document.createEvent("Events");
    if(keyEvent.initEvent){ keyEvent.initEvent("keydown", true, true); }
    keyEvent.keyCode = 13;
    keyEvent.which = 13;
    document.dispatchEvent ? document.dispatchEvent(keyEvent) : document.fireEvent("onkeydown", keyEvent);
    document.getElementsByName("client")[0].dispatchEvent(keyEvent);')`

I'm using poltergeist (1.12), capybara (2.6.2), selenuim-webdriver (2.50), cucumber (>2.0)

Please let me know if there is any more details required.

Thank you.

Comment: Firstly your capybara and selenium-webdriver are massively out of date.  Secondly, I assume when you say "with UI" you mean when using Selenium, as opposed to when using Poltergeist.  The selenium driver does not support `#trigger` because using it is highly frowned upon.  This is because `#trigger` lets you do things users couldn't and should be avoided when at all possible.  You need to figure out why an element is overlapping the element you're trying to click and fix that (max page bigger, etc). Add actual HTML if you need help with that.

Comment: Also you want to use `page.assert_no_selector(:css, '.Select-loading-zone')` since has_no_css? just returns a boolean, and won't alert you to the condition not being met (it's for use when you want to make a decision on what to do next based on whether or not something exists). The no-js class on your html element is a little concerning too, like you have a JS error preventing full page load (enable js_errors: true) in your Poltergeist driver registration to see them logged.

Comment: @ThomasWalpole, "With UI" means using Selenium, as opposed to when using Poltergeists. Thank you for the tip on using `assert_no_selector`. Looking into a bit more, I have found another error that put up. Using poltergeist, the `fill_in` syntax does not work but works using selenium. I have tried `element.set([value])` but same issue in poltergeist. Would you recommend the correct way of filling in the value so that it would work in both Poltergiest and Selenium?

Comment: If it works with selenium, but not Poltergeist then most likely you are using JS features that Poltergeist doesn't support (it doesn't support ES2015  features like `let` etc.)  If you're using any of those, without transpiling to ES5, then Poltergeist won't fully load the page, and no different use of `fill_in` will help you.  Hence why the 'no-js' class shown in your HTML concerned me -- it would tend to indicate the page never fully loaded.  If you are sure that's not the issue then you need to post the HTML you're trying to fill in and the exact error message you get

Comment: @ThomasWalpole, I know that is it not throwing an error as I have captured the innerHTML before the fill in is being set. Please see below `<div class="Select-placeholder">Select...</div><div class="Select-input" style="display: inline-block;"><input name="client" role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="" aria-haspopup="false" aria-activedescendant="react-select-2--value" value="" style="box-sizing: content-box; width: 2px;">`

Comment: So the page has loaded correctly but trying to set the `input[name=client]' does not. I have tried the executing JS script as well, `page.find(:css, "input[name$='client']").set(client_name)`

Comment: So it has a width of 2px??  So basically hidden on the page, and has been replaced by some JS driven widget -- you need to interact with the same elements a user would actually interact with, as a user would interact with them.

Comment: @ThomasWalpole, thank you all the help. After taking a look at the react control a bit more, using screenshots during the steps, it was a place holder on the control causing the issue. Please see the link https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/832